# Java how to do this with Border (with JFrame)

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, border

I am trying to make a Sudoku game but got stuck in drawing borders to divide boundaries.

For example,[image]

Inside one Panel, how can I set borders like that?

Comment: You could try a gridlayout, and and use lineborders, and make sure there's no offset. I might not be perfet but should be worth a try. Otherwise make a custom component, which is much more work but will be perfect

Comment: Use nested GridLayouts with gaps.

Comment: [The Java™ Tutorials: How to Use GridLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html)

Comment: If the backing JPanel has a black background, then black lines will show through in the grid gaps.